# Custom annotation processor in spring

Tags: spring, annotations, maven-3

i've written thi annotation

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Encrypt {

}
```

and its processor...

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("it.trecube.annotation.Encrypt")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
public class EncryptProcessor extends AbstractProcessor{

    public EncryptProcessor(){
        super();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        String className = null;
        String packageName = null;
        String fqClassName = null;
        for (Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Encrypt.class)) {
            if (elem.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS) {
                //              Encrypt encrypt = elem.getAnnotation(Encrypt.class);
                //              String message = "annotation found in " + elem.getSimpleName();
                //              processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.NOTE, message);
                TypeElement classElement = (TypeElement) elem;
                PackageElement packageElement = (PackageElement) classElement.getEnclosingElement();

                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                        Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                        "annotated class: @Encrypt" , elem);

                className = classElement.getSimpleName().toString();
                packageName = packageElement.getQualifiedName().toString();
                fqClassName = classElement.getQualifiedName().toString();

                if (fqClassName != null) {
                    processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                            Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                            "fqClassName: "+fqClassName , elem);
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("velocity.properties");
                    try {
                        props.load(url.openStream());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                                Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                                "annotated class: " + classElement.getQualifiedName()+"->\n"+
                                        e.getMessage(), elem);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return true;
                    }
                    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine(props);
                    ve.init();

                    VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();

                    vc.put("className", className);
                    vc.put("packageName", packageName);


                    Template vt = ve.getTemplate("encrypt.vm");
                    File file = new File("src/main/java/"+fqClassName.replace(".", "/")+"_Encrypt.aj");
                    try {
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

                        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                                Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                                "creating source file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());


                        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                                Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                                "applying velocity template: " + vt.getName());

                        vt.merge(vc, bw);

                        bw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
                                Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                                "applying velocity error: " + vt.getName()+"->\n"+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true; // no further processing of this annotation type
    }
```

I've tested all into a maven  client project and all work, but when i try to use it into an existing spring (full maven build) project not work...
Can someone help me??
Tnx

Comment: Could you be more specific when saying that it doesn't work? Which problem are you facing? Could you report the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved adding this...

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you created the `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file in the project where you have your annotation processor? This file should contain the fully qualified name of your processor. Also, with maven, you specify which annotation processors to use in the build by configuring the `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>com.mycompany.MyAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, having the annotation processor in the same project as you're using it might cause some problems with maven, so if you have not done it already, I suggest that you extract your annotation processor and annotations into a separate maven project.

Comment: I think that the problem is maven...the output of "mvn clean compile" command say

... [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date ...

so nothing is done...

In the test client all work only when maven compile...

Comment: If `mvn clean compile`says `Nothing to compile`, then something must be wrong with your maven project. Are you sure your folder structure is correct? This only happens for me if `mvn compile` does not find any source files at all.

Comment: p.s. annotation and annotation.processor are in separate project

Comment: The folder structure is correct, and into target/classes there are all compiled classes although "mvn clean compile" says Nothing to compile...

Comment: I discovered that the compile process is executed by the aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile so maven compiler say nothing to compile